# Correct way to use the same code in multiple cs files

Tags: c#

How can I repeat this an any CS file (before the `namespace` definition) without physically copying it from file to file?

```
#if ACAD
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

using _AcGe = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using _AcAp = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using _AcDb = Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using _AcEd = Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using _AcGi = Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface;
using _AcClr = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Colors;
using _AxApp = AutoCAD;
#endif

#if BCAD
using Teigha.Runtime;

using _AcTrx = Teigha.Runtime;
using _AcGe = Teigha.Geometry;
using _AcAp = Bricscad.ApplicationServices;
using _AcDb = Teigha.DatabaseServices;
using _AcEd = Bricscad.EditorInput;
using _AcGi = Teigha.GraphicsInterface;
using _AcClr = Teigha.Colors;
using _AxApp = BricscadApp; // COM
using _AxDb = BricscadDb; // COM
using Teigha.DatabaseServices;
using Teigha.Geometry;
#endif

#if ZCAD
using ZwSoft.ZwCAD.Runtime;

using _AcTrx = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.Runtime;
using _AcGe = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.Geometry;
using _AcAp = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.ApplicationServices;
using _AcDb = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.DatabaseServices;
using _AcEd = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.EditorInput;
using _AcGi = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.GraphicsInterface;
using _AcClr = ZwSoft.ZwCAD.Colors;
using _AxApp = ZWCAD; // COM
#endif
```

Comment: You can wait until C# 10 and use global using

Comment: Perhaps you can create a template file?

Comment: @TheGeneral I have not heard of C# 10. Will have to research.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I'll look into it.

Comment: visual studio allows you to create new item templates (as well as full project templates).  [Project & Item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thanks. It may be that my code of interest can be re-works to avoid the need for all this but I hit a couple of brick walls. I'll do an new question explaining.